# Find all the resistors in the circuit shown below, knowing that β=200, Vcc = +15 V, VE = 1, VC = 0.55*Vcc V, IC = 1 mA, and VBE = 0.7 V

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics

I have this BJT circuit, and I am asked to find all the resistors. This is my solution but I am not sure if it is correct.
[image: BJT Circuit]

Comment: Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: Ditto what winny says, you won't get exactly the same result but, it will give you some confidence about your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone, I don't know how to simulate a circuit. could you suggest an online simulator please?

Comment: Your calculation looks good. But typical we pick the voltage divider current 10 x Ib. Thus R2 = 1.7V/(10 *5uA) = 34k and R1 = (15V- 1.7V)/(11 * 5uA) = 240k  Look here https://tinyurl.com/2je4pbbm

Comment: @YousefZerini What does the class ask you to use as a design method? G36 points out one of the usual rules. But it isn't cast in concrete and a teacher may want other things (such as a low sensitivity to ambient temperature variations.) Without knowing what you are being taught there are different methods only some of which may be acceptable to the teacher. Can you provide any information about that?

Comment: Falstad for online. LTspice for offline.

Comment: Draw the circuit using CircuitLab (click icon in your edit window). Then simulate (DC Analysis).

Comment: I was only asked to find the values of the resistors. I am just unsure of my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given:

- \$V_{_\text{CC}}=15\:\text{V}\$
- \$V_{_\text{EE}}=0\:\text{V}\$ (ground)
- \$I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}=1\:\text{mA}\$
- \$V_{_{\text{E}_\text{Q}}}=1\:\text{V}\$
- \$V_{_{\text{BE}_\text{Q}}}=700\:\text{mV}\$
- \$\beta=200\$

I'll add the rule that the stiffness of the voltage divider at the base should such that about \$\frac1{10}\text{th}\$ of the quiescent \$I_{_\text{C}}\$ should exist in the divider, itself. The Thevenin of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, \$R_1\mid\mid R_2\$, is what supplies the base current to the BJT. If the Thevenin impedance is too large, then variations in base current due to signal variations will lead to significant voltage drop variations at the base, which act to counter the signal as negative feedback. *(It's already the case that \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ variations due to signal changes will provide still more NFB. Mitigating the NFB from the divider makes sense.)*

So, you can right away get \$R_{_\text{C}}=\frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-0.55\,\cdot\, V_{_\text{CC}}}{1\:\text{mA}}=6.75\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_{_\text{E}}=\frac{V_{_{\text{E}_\text{Q}}}}{1\:\text{mA}\,\cdot\,\frac{\beta+1}{\beta}}=995\:\Omega\$.

Now, it follows that \$V_{_{\text{B}_\text{Q}}}=V_{_{\text{E}_\text{Q}}}+V_{_{\text{BE}_\text{Q}}}=1.7\:\text{V}\$.

We appear to agree, so far.

From my added rule: \$R_1=\frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_{\text{B}_\text{Q}}}}{\frac1{10}\,\cdot\,I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}+\frac1{\beta}\,\cdot\,I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}}=127\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2=\frac{V_{_{\text{B}_\text{Q}}}}{\frac1{10}\,\cdot\,I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}}=17\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

*(Note that I included the base current when computing \$R_1\$ but did not include the base current when computing \$R_2\$. That's simply because \$R_1\$ must supply \$R_2\$'s current as well as the base current for the BJT.)*

That's it.

Making some adjustments to the 2N2222 (saturation current changes only as its \$\beta=200\$, already) to make it have \$V_{_{\text{BE}_\text{Q}}}=700\:\text{mV}\$, here's what I get from simulating the circuit using it:

```
       --- Operating Point ---

V(vc):   8.24796     voltage
V(vb):   1.70023     voltage
V(ve):   0.999986    voltage
V(vcc):  15  voltage
Ic(Q1):  0.0010003   device_current
Ib(Q1):  4.70885e-06     device_current
Ie(Q1):  -0.00100501     device_current
I(R1):   0.00100501  device_current
I(R2):   0.0010003   device_current
I(R3):   0.000104723     device_current
I(R4):   0.000100014     device_current
I(V1):   -0.00110503     device_current
```